# MobileAccessibility plugin is not installed / Not able to set custom font zoom - Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to get the MobileAccessibility plugin to work.
I tried following the docs by running

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/mobile-accessibility
```

I goes through without errors.

My ionic info is:

```
$ ionic info                                             

global packages:                                                                                                  
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0                             
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1                             
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0                             

local packages:                                                                                                
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7              
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0              
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1              
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3      
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0

System:                                                                                                       
Node       : v6.9.1                                  
OS         : Windows 10                              
Xcode      : not installed                           
ios-deploy : not installed                           
ios-sim    : not installed                           
npm        : 3.10.8
```

and here is my cordova plugin list:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin list
> cordova plugin ls
✔ Running command - done!
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4-dev "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-deploy 0.6.7 "IonicDeploy"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility 1.0.5-dev "Mobile Accessibility"
```

Now when I run the application using `ionic cordova run android` via USB debugging this pops up in the console log:

> Native: tried calling MobileAccessibility.usePreferredTextZoom, but the MobileAccessibility plugin is not installed.
>
> Install the MobileAccessibility plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility.git'

I've searched all over and can't seem to find a solution.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Probably related to this: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/1666, same issue, 12 days ago. From ihadeed: "Just pushed a commit to fix this. Will be available in the next patch release."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone still experiencing problems..

Updating Ionic CLI, Ionic-Cordova and Android platform fixed whatever was wrong and I was able to set the font size to a custom value using `setTextZoom(80);`